# Insertar valores en un List<Class>, y mostrar un solo resultado (2 preguntas)

Tags: java, html, jsp

estoy haciendo una página web de coches para practicar. En esta página, se muestran 3 coches (digamos Kia, Ferrari y Mercedes) los cuales saldrán los siguientes atributos:

- Marca
- Gamma de coche (alta o normal)
  Un boton donde se seleccionará el coche.

Bien, por otro lado tengo una CLASE llamada Cotxe, que alberga los atributos Código, Marca, Cavallos y Modelo. Por lo tanto, en la página web he de crear una lista con los atributos de la clase:

```
List<Coche> cochesInit = new ArrayList<Coche>();
```

El problema es que cuando voy a insertar los datos me dice **No Suitable Method found for add**

```
cochesInit.add(1,"Kia",190,"Modelo");
```

Por lo que no puedo insertar ningún nuevo Coche.

Por otro lado, al presionar **seleccionar** la página ha de refrescarse mostrando sólo el coche seleccionado.

Mi código actualmente es el siguiente:

```
<%!
    List<Cotxe> cotxesInit = new ArrayList<Cotxe>();
    String cotxeDiv = "";   
%>
<%
   cotxesInit.add(1,"Kia",190,"Gamma Alta");
%>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Cotxes</title>
    <!-- CSS -->

    <link href="owncss/concessionari.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">


    <!-- JAVA SCRIPT -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <h1>Cotxes</h1>
            </div>
        </div>                

        <div class="col-md-3 divCotxe">
            <div class="row">

                <%  
                    cotxeDiv = "kia-carens";
                    pageContext.setAttribute("cotxeDiv", cotxeDiv);
                %>
                <img class = "img-responsive" src='img/<%=cotxeDiv%>.png'/>
                <p>Marca: Mercedes</p>
                <p>Normal</p>                          


                <a href="concessionari.jsp?cotxe=${cotxeDiv}">Select</a>

            </div></div>

        <div class="col-md-3 divCotxe">
            <div class="row">

                <% 
                    cotxeDiv = "ferrari";
                    pageContext.setAttribute("cotxeDiv", cotxeDiv);
                %>
                <img class = "img-responsive" src='img/<%=cotxeDiv%>.jpg'/>

                <p>Marca: Alta gama</p>
                <p>Ferrari</p>                       


                <a href="concessionari.jsp?cotxe=${cotxeDiv}">Select</a>
            </div></div>

        <div class="col-md-3 divCotxe">
            <div class="row">
                <%   
                    cotxeDiv = "mercedes";
                    pageContext.setAttribute("cotxeDiv", cotxeDiv);
                %>
                <img class = "img-responsive" src='img/<%=cotxeDiv%>.jpeg'/>
                <p>Marca: Alta gama</p>
                <p>Mercedes</p> 
                <a href="concessionari.jsp?cotxe=${cotxeDiv}">Select</a>
            </div></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Si no me he explicado bien por favor preguntadme e intentaré formular la pregunta de otra forma. Un saludo.

Comment: Hola, la firma del metodo `List.add` puedes verla en la [documentacion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add-int-E-). Si te fijas, no hay ningun metodo que reciba los argumentos que le estas pasando. Lo correcto seria pasarle una instancia de `Coche`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me imagino que lo que tratas de hacer es lo siguiente:

```
Coche coche = new Coche (
  1,
  "Kia",
  190,
  "Modelo"
);

cochesInit.add(coche);
```

Comment: Si la pregunta con para Java por qué la respuesta es para C#?

Comment: Es casi similar en los dos lenguages. No tengo java en este momento. Necesita una instancia de coche.

Comment: Es muy diferente tu código a como se haría en Java. Esto puede traer más confusión al OP que claramente no tiene mucha experiencia, por lo menos con Java.

Comment: perfecto ahora es java.

Comment: Claro, justo de este modo si que lo entiendo ya que solía hacerlo, pero como he empezado ahora a usar los List, ArrayList y MAP, me he ido por las ramas y liado totalmente. Muchísimas gracias a ambos!

Comment: @Papillon si esta respuesta solucionó tu problema por favor márcala como Aceptada. Saludos.

Comment: Otra duda que tengo es cómo haría para, una vez selecciono un coche, se recargue la página y sólo aparezca ese coche. Un saludo.